# Add-AzIotHubRoutingEndpoint cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-iot-hub, az

I need to create some custom Endpoints for my Iot Hub through PowerShell. The cmdlet [Add-AzIotHubRoutingEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.iothub/Add-AzIotHubRoutingEndpoint?view=azps-4.3.0) isn't sufficient since it doesn't provide the possibility to customize the BatchFrequencyInSeconds and the MaxChunkSizeInBytes properties.

Can this be achieved somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The Set-AzIotHub has a parameter -RoutingProperties and in this way you can achieve greater customization. What I did was the following:

```
# Create an endpoint object
$customEndpoint = New-Object "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.IotHub.Models.PSRoutingStorageContainerEndpoint"
# Set its contents...

# Get the routing properties from your Iot Hub
$routingProperties = $iotHub.Properties.Routing
# Add this endpoint to the specified category, mine was a storage container endpoint
$routingProperties.Endpoints.StorageContainers.Add($customEndpoint)

# Then call Set-AzIotHub
$iotHub = Set-AzIotHub `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -Name "$($ResourceGroupName)$($IotHubSettings.NameSuffix)" `
    -RoutingProperties $routingProperties
```